# Redirect with .htacces to a controller with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to redirect my `example.com` web page to `example.com/controller`

How do I do this with `.htaccess`?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+remove+index.php

Comment: I dont want to remove the index.php , I want to redirect mypage.com to mypage.com/controller

Comment: you want it to display the controller? or do you want the controller to appear in the url?

Comment: Then... https://www.google.com/search?q=.htaccess+redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^controller$ / [L]
```

Comment: That would probably knock out all of his other .htaccess CI Rewrites - use with caution!